# Which version of Java 1.6 is the most stable?

Tags: java, java-6

Experts need some help in deciding stable java version. We are planing to move our application from java 1.4 to 1.6, Which version of Java 1.6 is stabler one.

Answer (score 6):

The best idea is to use the last version of Java 6 (u_45).  And of course Java 6 is now EOL'ed too, so you should *really* be upgrading to Java 7 ... or beyond.

(And next time, you shouldn't wait so long to update your platform. Java 1.4.2 became "out of date" in 2004.  2004 to 2011 is a LONG time ago in IT terms.)

Comment: +1: Java 5.0 has been "End Of Life" of free support since Oct '09. ;)

Comment: -1: I did some search a while ago because my Eclipse kept crashing.  It turned out a few 1.6 versions of JDK causes the problem, at the time of my search, included the latest "stable" version.  People also suggested the highest version which worked with Eclipse.

Comment: @fchen - that may be so, but upgrading to the latest (now last) version is the correct answer.  And upgrading to Java 7 is a better answer.  The stuff you found using Google is most likely out of date.

Comment: @StephenC - let me make it clearer:

Comment: @StephenC - let me make it clearer. Q: which version of java7 is most stable? A: use the latest version of Java 7(u_xx). Q: this does not answer my question, when I was at java6, I knew for a few month, 1.6_21 was the latest version that won't crash Eclipse, 1.6_22-25 all had that problem (number may be wrong, just a concept). I wonder for Java7 do you have a stable recommendation. A: always try you luck with the latest and keep upgrading ...  Q: my users won't be happy, my boss wants the Eclipse to work by the end of day.

Comment: @fchen - You are asking the wrong question.  The real question **you** should be asking is the following: "Q: At date yyyy/mm/dd - what published version of Java will work best with Eclipse A.B.C and the following plugins".  And the Answer will be of the form "A: Try it out for yourself, and repeat this each time a new release comes out.".  Also suggest to your boss that he should take out a Oracle Java maintenance contract and/or pay for Eclipse support ... and use those to get the relevant bugs identified and fixed.

Comment: My point is that "the most stable" doesn't have an objective answer, and even the subjective answer is highly time dependent.  My second point I've already made ... but you seem to have missed ... just 'cos you found something using Google doesn't make it correct.  Certainly, it doesn't mean it is *still* correct.

Answer (score 5):

It's [JDK1.6_25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)(at the time of writing). Just check out the oracle's site.

Comment: This JDK version won't be as "latest" in future releases of JDK 6.

Comment: @The Elite: Yes. In future there may be JDK7 or jdk1.6_26 and on...

Answer (score 4):

I'm interested in this issue too and wanted to share my experience.

I question the statement that "they are all stable" - in the sense of 'working' rather than 'set in stone', at least.  Perhaps for undemanding apps any JDK is as good as any other - we have rather more stringent requirements.

My experience is that both 6u12 and 6u25 have serious memory leak bugs that affect us.  6u12 has a concurrency bug, and 6u25 leaks majorly under load when escape analysis (a major compiler optimization that's turned on by default) is enabled.

I am  currently testing 6u21 with better success so far.  Reviewing the Sun bug DB has revealed no serious issues in that revision, but I am interested in other opinions.

It's also clear from the JDK version release notes [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html) that some are relatively minor revisions, while others consolidate a lot of important bug fixes.

Comment: This information is 2+ years out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Once a Java 6 version is released its not changed, which is stable. Take the most recent release version. Avoid the beta and early access versions.